# before_filter works differently in development and production modes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I am working on a generic controller to provide default functionality to the RESTful actions, but I am having trouble when I need to add additional routes.  The default behavior I am after renders all actions in either an index view, or a show view.  My code is setup like this (lots of unrelated code is trimmed);

```
module RestController extend ActiveSupport::Concern
  included do
    before_action: setup_index_view, 
                   only: [:index, :new, :create] << @additional_index_routes
    before_action: setup_show_view, 
                   only: [:show, :edit:, update, :destroy] << @additional_show_routes
  end

  def setup_rest_controller(_additional_index_routes,
                            _additional_show_routes)
    @additional_index_routes = _additional_index_routes
    @additional_show_routes = _additional_show_routes 
  end

  def setup_index_view
    # default behavior, sets @{collection_name} = {Model.collection}
    # code trimmed
  end

  def setup_show_view
    # default behavior, sets @{instance_name} = {Model.find(params[:id]}
    # code trimmed
  end
end

class Order < ApplicationController
  def initialize
    setup_rest_controller(
      _additional_show_routes: [:quote, :contract, invoice_report])
  end

  def setup_index_view
    #override default behavior to filter andpaginate collection
    @orders = Orders.active.search(search_terms).paginate
  end

  #accept default behavior for setup_views
end
```

In development, this code is working fine (I admit that surprises me a little), but in production the additional routes are not running the setup_show_method.  The only difference in the gem file is that development includes rspec-rails.  Does anyone know why this code would behave differently?

**EDIT** 
As soon as I hit post, the 'why' hit me.  In development the code is reloaded at each request, and in production it is only loaded once...at first load `@additional_show_routes` is not set, and therefore no additional routes are added to the `before_action call`.  New question then...how do I get the desired behavior?

Adding a call to `before_action` in the `OrdersController` overrides the one in `RestController` and breaks the default functionality.

Adding a call to `before_action` in `setup_rest_controller` throws a NoMethodError.

When you add a concern like this, is there a method like `new` that I can use instead of `setup_rest_controller` to set `@additional_show_views` earlier?

Comment: Are you certain that taking over the `initialize` method isn't breaking default behavior?

Comment: This is the kind of code that I would revert instantly because of the inherent complexity. Are you really sure that the abstraction is worth all of that struggle? Is there no way to implement that behavior in ApplicationController?

Answer (score 0):

This feels like a hack, but it seems to get the desired result;

```
class OrdersController < ApplicationController

  prepend_before_action Proc.new { send :setup_index_view}, 
      only: [:new_restful_action]

  def setup_index_view
    #override default behavior to filter andp aginate collection
    @orders = Orders.active.search(search_terms).paginate
  end

  #accept default behavior for setup_views
end
```

I also drop all references to `@additional_{X}_routes` in `RestController`.  I don't know that `prepend_` is required in the code as written above, but in my actual code there are other before_filters that need to run after `@additional_{X}_routes`...